# Edit permissions required on this Google Analytics property?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

In Search Console (Settings > Associations), I'm getting the following notice and am unsure how to resolve it. In the 'Property Access Management' section of my Analytics Admin section, I'm listed as the administrator with full control of property. How can I resolve this notice?

[image]